# How do i get top 5 score in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to get top 5 score from student table.
table looks like that.

```
   table: student

   id name   score

   1    a     100
   2    b     100
   3    c     90
   4    d     87
   5    e     85
   6    f     88
   7    g     83
   9    h     92
```

if i do

```
   select name,score from student order by score desc limit 5

   a    100
   b    100
   h     92
   c     90
   f     88
```

however, I want to see this result

```
   a    100
   b    100
   h     92
   c     90
   f     88
   d     87
```

I am trying to figure out duplicated score as count one
 Any solution? 
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "duplicated score"? Why are you excluding e and g from your desired result?

Comment: If you are trying to find the rankings rather than a straight count, this post has some interesting techniques for achieving that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333665/mysql-rank-function

Comment: I think you mean to say "I cannot filter out the duplicated score." in which case John Conde's answer is for you.

Comment: Are you trying to count the number of students that scored 100? or the count of students that scored each grade?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT s.*
FROM student AS s
  JOIN
    ( SELECT DISTINCT score
      FROM student
      ORDER BY score DESC
          LIMIT 5
    ) AS lim
    ON s.score = lim.score 
ORDER BY s.score DESC ;
```

Comment: i don't knew joins can be used like this also, Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way:

```
select s.*
from student s
where s.score >= (select score
                  from (select distinct score from student order by score desc limit 5) s
                  order by score
                  limit 1
                 )
```

This gets the scores in descending order in the inner most subquery.  It limits this to five distinct scores.  Then, it find the smallest value, and returns all rows that have this score or greater.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html):

```
SELECT 
    score
    COUNT(*) AS score_count
FROM 
    student 
GROUP BY
    score
ORDER BY
    score desc 
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: This returns five rows.  The example results have six rows.

Comment: Then change the LIMIT to 6

Comment: how do he can know if he has more number of records same???...u are saying limit it to 6 ?

Comment: They can change it to whatever they want. If they want six, they can change it to six. If they want more they can change it accordingly. It's basic SQL.

Comment: he want to say that same(duplicate) records count as one row, so my argument was , one won't be knowing how much rows will be having same records

Answer (score 0):

here is [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/271ecf/2)

```
  SELECT s.id, s.name,s.score FROM tbl_student AS s INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM tbl_student ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 0,5) AS s2 ON s2.id=s.id order by s.score desc
```